# Breeze Server with multiple foreign keys to same table doesn't expand properly

Tags: breeze

I have a complex data model where I need to have two foreign keys to the same table that point to different records.  In my example I have a client table and I'm trying to keep track of which staff remember created vs modified the record.  My object is setup like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class shgt_WfClient
{
    public int wfClientId { get; set; }
    public string SearchName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual tblStaff tblStaffCreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual tblStaff tblStaffModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

My controller has a very basic setup:

```
[Breeze.WebApi2.BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider<Models.DataEntities> _contextProvider = new Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider<Models.DataEntities>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Models.shgt_WfClient> WfClient()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.shgt_WfClient;
    }
```

When using $expand I  always get tblStaffCreatedBy, even if I specify tblStaffModifiedBy.  If I try to get both I only ever get tblStaffCreatedBy.  Is this a bug where you can't have multiple foreign key references to the same table?  If so, this would be a pretty big deal breaker as some of the complex Enterprise databases I work with can have several joins back to the same table via foreign keys.  I would note that I'm using the database first with Diagram in EF and NOT code first.

I have tested and verified that my model is wired up properly in EF via C# code:

```
List<Models.shgt_WfClient> clients = (db.shgt_WfClient.Include("tblStaffModifiedBy").Include("tblStaffCreatedBy").Where(a => a.wfClientId == 1)).ToList();
```

-Costoda

Comment: I may be missing something glaring but in your model I don't see any foreign keys at all - how does it know who created or modified it?

Comment: I updated the description of the problem - I didn't cut and paste all the code in - I updated to include the fields.  I'm using the Database First diagram option in EF.  I've verified that my model is working properly via C# code outside of Breeze.

Comment: You are able to do the expands properly in C#, using LINQ?

Comment: Yes - I'm able to see the expanded properties without problems in C# using LINQ.

Comment: In my test for this scenario, Breeze is working properly and is able to include the navigation property/properties I specified. Can I see how you construct your client query as well as the generated Breeze client side metadata for the entities in question?